# Search 1000 Word Document For 15,000 Phrases

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a database of ~15,000 multiple word phrases which range in length from 2-7 words. I want to be able to search a small document (~1000 words) to see which phrases it contains.  I'm basically looking for the best way to achieve this.

I have currently have the data in MySQL in two tables:

**phrases** *(~15,000 rows)*

 phrase_id

 phrase

 length   *(number of words in the phrase)*

**documents** *(100s/day)*

document_id

 text

The phrases list stays the same, new documents are being added all the time.

As far as I can tell the best way to do this is with some sort of index.  Ideally when the document is added it would be indexed to see which phrases it contains so that when a search is done later the results come back immediately.

I've considered how to do this in MySQL

1. Tokenize the document into 2 word phrases finding phrases which begin with the token
2. Iterate through the results increasing the length of the token - if (phrase length == token length) {match} else {keep for next token length}.
3. Store the results in a new table **document_phrases** phrase_id, document_id

This all seems like a lot of overhead though and I'm wondering if an external tool like Sphinx would be able to do this more efficiently?  I've looked into it but it seems that it's mostly for searching lots of documents for 1 phrase, not searching 1 document for many phrases.

Is there some technique that I've completely missed?  Please note that, whilst technically interesting, solutions using java/python are beyond what I'm planning to learn for this project

Comment: Your algorithm looks OK. PHP is quite useful for this kind of string-manipulation stuff.  You may want to load each document's text and process it with PHP into phrases of length 2-7, then look up those phrases one by one.  That should be relatively efficient for documents of reasonable length -- the Bible and the Bhagavad-Gita:OK. The United States tax law, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Full Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).  The examples given, and the ability to find relevance might give you some ideas or alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Having read through it though it is the reverse of what I'm trying to achieve (search many documents for few phrases rather than search a few documents for many phrases)